# Ruby on Rails -- Commontator for multiple devise models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, comments, initializer

Now I have three devise models.
Admins,
AlphaTeamUsers &
BetaTeamUsers

I am currently using the gem 'commontator' for comments on the Posts model. I want all three devise models to be able to comment but I don't really know how to do that:

I've tried using (config/intializers/commontator.rb):

```
if admin_signed_in?
   config.current_user_proc = lambda { |controller| controller.current_admin }
elsif beta_team_member_signed_in?
   config.current_user_proc = lambda { |controller| controller.current_beta_team_user }
end
```

But obviously you can't really use devise helpers here.
I'd be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Edit: Basically I'm having trouble with the admin_signed_in? and beta_team_member_signed_in? because they don't work

Comment: From your last comment, is your issue that you can't access current_admin / current_beta_team_user?

Comment: @Mark Basically I'm having trouble with the admin_signed_in? and beta_team_member_signed_in?